# Set macOS to output Limited RGB (16–235) color

Tags: macos, display, color

My projector only supports limited RGB color. That means it expects all RGB values to be in the range of 16–235.

macOS High Sierra appears to be outputting full RGB (0–255) color to my projector. This means the darkest blacks and highest whites get crushed, and the detail lost.

How can I make macOS output limited RGB color, instead of full?

Comment: [This page](https://www.mathewinkson.com/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor) might help, but it looks pretty complicated.

Comment: @IconDaemon Thanks, but that won't do anything in my situation. It's intended for force macOS to output RGB instead of YCBCR. My Mac is already outputting RGB, but it's RGB full instead of RGB limited. (I tried it last night anyway—it's super easy if SIP is turned off—and it predictably had no effect.)

Comment: I am responsible for > 100 projectors (mostly Epson) and have never experienced this problem. Maybe a new projector is warranted? There's nothing you can set on the projector itself? BTW/ what are you using to connect to the projector? HDMI, VGA, MiniDisplay Port?

Comment: @IconDaemon Connected via HDMI. I semi-lied in the question for the sake of simplification—I technically *can* set the projector to full RGB, but then all my other sources which are set to limited RGB will look wrong, and going into the projector's menu to change the setting every time is a major PITA. These other sources include old-ish game consoles (like the Wii U) that simply don't support full RGB, so limited is the standard I need everything to output.

Comment: @IconDaemon BTW, this isn't necessarily a problem you'd notice if you're not (A) watching movies and (B) looking for it. I basically discovered last night that I've had this misconfigured for the past year.

Comment: Maybe some of the CG functions may be useful here? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_display_services?language=objc

There seem to be various things with the gamma table, but I honestly don't know enough about graphics to say if that will do what you need.

Comment: @1110101001 Thank you as always! I ended up switching my Wii U to use component cables in order to resolve this; for some reason that console will only output full RGB when connected via component. So now I just have everything set to full RGB across the board.

Comment: I think I have a suggestion on a direction you can investigate: seems like many macs have the opposite problem where they treat external monitors as TVs and output in YCbCr and limited rgb mode. The fix is to patch EDID, as you can find online. Maybe you should do the opposite..

Comment: @Wowfunhappy `MonitorPanel.framework` private framework has some methods about detecting projector. You can play around with that. Maybe easiest way is to just use simbl or other means to match the `isProjector` check. I'm sure it's probably also possible to do via display overrides, but there isn't any documentation on format aside from basic `scaled-resolutions` key

Comment: @1110101001 OS X does not know I am using a projector, so that's not it. (There's a button for projector calibration which does not appear in System Preferences for my particular projector). Regardless, this isn't an active problem for me anymore, I set all of my inputs to use full rgb (including the massive pain in the neck called a Wii U) and that has been working. Thank you for thinking of me though!

Comment: I meant maybe if it's not detecting as a projector, you can patch `isProjector` to make it think it's connected to a projector.

Comment: @1110101001 It's detected as a projector when I don't go through my HDMI matrix, but this has no effect on full vs limited rgb.